# Is there a faster way to sum product a column of one dataframe to rows of other dataframe without loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to sumproduct x rows of a dataframe column (App_table) to x columns of another dataframe row(numeric_col_data). I have currently done this using loops but since the dataframe is large (~2M rows) it takes hours to compute. Is there a faster way to accomplish the same.

```
      for (j in 1:nrow(Weighted_Scenario_table)) {
        Weighted_Scenario_table[j,i] <- sum(App_table[,i]*numeric_col_data[j,])
      }
    }
```

Comment: maybe using matrix multiplication i.e. `numeric_col_data %*% App_table`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 I guess type conversion is needed before matrix multiplication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can first convert your data frames to matrices and then apply matrix product as below

```
Weighted_Scenario_table <- as.matrix(numeric_col_data) %*% as.matrix(App_table)
```

Comment: Will this do a sumproduct or just multiplication?

Comment: @user2733655 it is sumproduct. You can try it with smaller example to check it out